# Maximum value of $|x-y|$

Tags: quadratics, maxima-minima

Given $x,y\in\mathbb R$ such that
$$5x^2+5y^2-6xy\ =\ 8$$
find the maximum value of $|x-y|$.

**My attempt**

$5x^2 - 6yx + (5y^2-8)\ =\ 0$

$x\ =\ \dfrac{6y\pm\sqrt{(6y)^2-4(5)(5y^2-8)}}{10} = \dfrac{6y\pm\sqrt{160-64y^2}}{10} = \dfrac{3y\pm2\sqrt{10-4y^2}}{10}$

$5y^2 - 6xy + (5x^2-8)\ =\ 0$

$y\ =\ \dfrac{3x\pm2\sqrt{10-4x^2}}{10}$

$|x-y|\ =\ \dfrac{\left|3(y-x)\pm2\sqrt{10-4y^2}\mp2\sqrt{10-4x^2}\right|}{10}$

What do I do from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: We can write $$P= 5x^2 +5y^2-6xy-8 =5 (x-y)^2+4xy-8 =5 (x-y)^2 +(x+y)^2-(x-y)^2-8=4 (x-y)^2 +(x+y)^2-8$$ Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 3):

You tried to solve for both $x$ in terms of $y$ and $y$ in terms of $x$.
Try expressing everything as either a function of $x$ or of $y$.

Answer (score 0):

We'll prove that $|x-y|\leq\sqrt2$.
Indeed, we need to prove that 
$$(x-y)^2\leq2\cdot\frac{5x^2+5y^2-6xy}{8}$$ or
$$(x+y)^2\geq0.$$
The equality occurs for $x+y=0$ and $x-y=\sqrt2$ for example.

Id est, the answer is $\sqrt2$.

Comment: Although recent your answers or all answers are guaranteed by exact answer, I think the step of proof must start from $|x-y|\leq k$. It is stupid conclusion that the answer is $\sqrt2$.

Comment: @Takahiro Waki I thought that the following step was obvious: If $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ and $y=-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ we have $k\geq\sqrt2$ and the rest you saw.